# Solution to use Websocket on .Net CF 3.5

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-cf-3.5

I am developing DDP client application for embedded Windows CE, Which has .Net compact framework 3.5. 
   DDP has developed on top of Websocket, I can't find the solution/dll that supports websocket for .Net CF 3.5.

Looking for websocket library that supports .Net compact framework or any work around to this problem.

Comment: Are you looking for WebSocket client libraries? There are open source ones which you can manually port to .NET CF on your own, but generally speaking CF is quite a limited platform so you should check if any commercial libraries are available.

Comment: First of all Thanks for your reply Lex.
Yes, I am looking for WebSocket libraries can run on .Net compact framework. I have also tried to search for code that helps me develope Websocket on top of TCPSocket. But no luck.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: Noemax.WebSockets

> This package pulls in all the assemblies required for creating servers
>   and clients running on .NET Framework (server-side & client-side),
>   **.NET Compact Framework (server-side & client-side)**, Xamarin.iOS
>   (server-side & client-side), Xamarin.Android (server-side &
>   client-side), Windows Phone (client-side), Silverlight (client-side)
>   and Mono (server-side & client-side).

See here more datails:
[https://www.noemax.com/powerwebsockets/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Noemax.WebSockets/)

[image]

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var client = new WebSocketClient<WebSocketMessagingService>("ws://localhost:8080");
      client.Open();

      Console.WriteLine(client.Request<string>("Hello", "Hello there !!!"));
      Console.WriteLine(client.Request<string>("GoodBye"));
      Console.Read();
   }
```